# Turing machine with k-dimensional tape or k-regular tree

Tags: abstract-algebra, automata, turing-machines

The statement I read is  " In a k-dimensional tape, cells corresponds to elements of free commutative group of k generators. s.  There  are  2k  shifts, which correspond  to addition  of a  generator or its  negative.In a  k-regular tree,  the  cells correspond  to  the  elements of a  free group on  k  generators.  There  are  2k  shifts, which  correspond  to  premultiplication by  a  generator  or  its  inverse.  " It is cited from paper Relations Among Complexity Measures by  NICHOLAS  PIPPENGER . Could someone please explain this. (I don't have good background in abstract algebra , just know some definitions)